# Blackberry browser Javascript Time DST issues

Tags: javascript, blackberry, web, timezone

We are targeting Blackberry OS 6 and 7 devices, and are having issues with Javascript and daylight saving time. The behaviour we're seeing for different devices/OS versions is either:

- keeps DST setting till end of month (so switches at 1-Nov instead of 28-Oct for Europe this year)
- uses the same DST setting/time zone offset for the whole year (so after 28-Oct the time zone will be CET (+100), and before 28-OCt it will be CEST (+200), for the **whole** year)

More specific for different devices/versions:

- 9800 - 6.0.0.246: uses same offset for all dates
- 9780 - 6.0.0.285: uses same offset for all dates
- 9780 - 6.0.0.668: switches at end of month
- 9700 - 6.0.0.668: switches at end of month
- 9360 - 7.0.0.530: switches at end of month

Is anyone aware of these issues and/or a workaround?

I have found this Blackberry issue, which explains the 'same offset for all dates' issue, and I think they fixed it in the wrong way: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Javscript-GMT-Offfset-not-working-in-BB6-0-Devices-Non-Torch/td-p/815883

We also developed a test page, which reveals the issue by executing some simple document.write(new Date(timestamp)) statements, available here: http://bit.ly/QhJOIC

Answer (score 0):

One option if the web page is for online use only: then you could make a ajax call back to the server to get proper offset for this user.  This would then use a libary of your choice for providing the time zone and DST information.  Just return user location infromation to the server.

Comment: Yes, but we already retrieve the events from the server, so we could then simply do all date rendering server-side. We prefer to keep data server-side and presentation client-side though, and only exchange the timestamp.